# How to turn a dictionary into a dataframe with all the keys in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

```
def weights():
    saved = {}
    for i in range(len(bread_pairs["key_id"])):
        drawing = np.array(bread_pairs['bitmap'][i], dtype=np.uint8)
        new_test_cnn = drawing.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
        new_cnn_predict = model.predict(new_test_cnn, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
        w = model.layers[8].get_weights()
        w = list(w[0].flatten())
        saved[bread_pairs["key_id"][i]] = w
    return saved
```

I have this function that is creating a dictionary of key_ids and mapping them to an associated list of values of length 200. So for example my dictionary looks something like `saved = {key_id_1: [1,2,3...200], key_id_2: [1,2,...,200], ....}`
I would like to turn this dictionary into a dataframe with a column of key_ids and each element in the associated list of 200 becomes its own column. So there is a total of 201 columns where the first column is the first key_id and then the second column is the first element of the list, the third column is the second element of the list etc. And then the second row first column is the second key_id and then the second row second column is the first element of the key_id's second list and so on. Is there a way to convert this dictionary to a df? I have 10000 key_ids do the dimensions would be 10000x201. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Load the `dict` into a DataFrame using [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with the `orient` parameter, and reset the index with `.reset_index()`

  - This will create the DataFrame as requested, however, I recommend leaving the keys as the index, which should make it easier to perform calculations and address specific rows.
- If the columns should be named `0...201`, then use `df.columns = list(range(202))`, or use [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename specific columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
saved = {'key_id_1': list(range(201)), 'key_id_2': list(range(201))}

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(saved, orient='index')

# reset the index
df = df.reset_index()

# display(df)
      index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181  182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195  196  197  198  199  200
0  key_id_1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181  182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195  196  197  198  199  200
1  key_id_2  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  107  108  109  110  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119  120  121  122  123  124  125  126  127  128  129  130  131  132  133  134  135  136  137  138  139  140  141  142  143  144  145  146  147  148  149  150  151  152  153  154  155  156  157  158  159  160  161  162  163  164  165  166  167  168  169  170  171  172  173  174  175  176  177  178  179  180  181  182  183  184  185  186  187  188  189  190  191  192  193  194  195  196  197  198  199  200
```

### Alternative Implementation

- Create the DataFrame with `pandas.DataFrame`, transpose the DataFrame with [`pandas.DataFrame.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html), and then reset with `.reset_index()`.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(saved)
df = df.T.reset_index()
```